# Error in data.frame() arguments imply differing number of rows: 1, 0

Tags: r

Here's my code:

```
library(knitr)
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyverse)
library(readr)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(tibble)
library(ggradar)
library(scales)

skater_stats = read.csv("game_skater_stats.csv")
player_info = read.csv("player_info.csv")

q3 <- skater_stats %>%
  left_join(player_info, by = 'player_id') %>%
  group_by(player_id) %>%
  mutate(goals = mean(goals), assists = mean(assists), hits = mean(hits), giveaways = mean(giveaways)) %>%
  filter(lastName == "Backstrom" | lastName == "Crosby" | lastName == "Draisaitl" | lastName == "Kessel" | lastName == "Walkin" | lastName == "McDavid") %>%
  select(lastName, goals, assists, hits, giveaways, player_id) %>%
  distinct() %>%
  as_tibble(rownames = "lastName") %>%
  mutate_at(vars(-lastName), rescale) %>%
  select(c('lastName', 'goals', 'assists', 'hits', 'giveaways'))

ggradar(q3)
```

I'm trying to create a ggradar plot of some data, but when I run ggradar, I'm getting this error:

```
Error in data.frame(group = i, x = pathData[, j] * sin(angles[j - 1]),  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 1, 0
```

Which confuses me, because generally this error pops up only when `nrows != ncols`, right? However, my `q3` data frame looks as such:

```
lastName   goals      assists     hits     giveaways
Crosby    1.0000000 0.781765830 1.0000000  0.5034172
Backstrom 0.0000000 0.484151271 0.8924173  0.0000000
Kessel    0.6056602 0.000000000 0.0000000  0.5092990
Draisaitl 0.5675551 0.004395736 0.5663225  1.0000000
McDavid   0.9985185 1.000000000 0.3281105  0.4986486
```

I'm just trying to get an output like this, so the rows and columns can't be the same number:
[image]

Comment: *"this error pops up only when `nrows != ncols`"*, not really. The error occurs when a column is not created/updated to be the same length as the number of rows or an even divisor (for "recycling"). This can be seen with `data.frame(a=1:2,b=1:3)` (error) vice `data.frame(a=1:2,b=1:4)` (okay b/c column `a` is safely recycled, `1:2` is repeated to fill the 4 rows). In your case, it is saying that one if `pathData` or `angles` are empty (the 0 in `rows: 1, 0` of the error message). As to "why?", I don't know, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All,

A lot of you have been getting this error with #3/ ggradar:

Error in data.frame(group = i, x = pathData[,j] * sin(angles[j-1]), : arguments imply differing number of rows: 1, 0

If you are getting this, it's likely because your dataframe isn't coverting to a tibble correctly.

To resolve it, try to read in the files with the command read_csv() instead of read.csv

read_csv reads it in as a tibble, which prevents conversion issues later. read.csv reads it in as a dataframe.

Of note, you need to call library(readr) before using read_csv

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and it was definitely a tibble, but fixed it by converting the group from a factor to a character variable.

Comment: Perhaps you could elaborate more, such as providing code specific for the OP's question?